# Is this question closeworthy?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Visual C++ won't create the dll file and stops at the *.lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779921/visual-c-wont-create-the-dll-file-and-stops-at-the-lib)

and if so, what is the best choice of close reason? Never voted to close before but this q does not seem to add much to the discourse.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure we have all had the experience of struggling with an *"Inconceivable!"* problem for hours only to discover that we have overlooked something trivial.

[image: I do not think it means what you think it means]

That seem to make the question genuine. Leave it.

Comment: +1 for the princess bride quote.

Comment: @Gamecat - Yes, I guess deciding whether a q adds to the discourse is subjective enough for this to be valid

Answer (score 0):

If the question owner finds the answer, the best way is if he/she answers the question and accept it. So can other people benefit from his findings.